# How to get contrast in R

Tags: r

I want to find linear regression with contrasts for wages in different states in a large dataset. I've only found methods for small sets of data with only two columns and I don't know how to apply them to my large scale data with 20 levels.

I have import table data1 from to R which looks like this (I want to ignore columns other than wages and state):

```
  person_no wages state sex age education kids
1       123  1000     1   f  24        12    1
2       124  1250     5   m  45         8    0
3       125 15000    12   f  56        16    3
4       126  8500    24   m  34        16    2
...
```

I've tried to create levels for states with `levels(data1$state)` but I've got
error message `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Therefore I've created dummy variables with

```
S1 <- ifelse(data1$state==1,1,0) and I don't know how to proceed.
```

I've tried also `contrast()`:

```
contrasts(data1$wage) = contr.treatment(16)
```

but I only get errors. Please help me!

Comment: So the question is how to define `state` as a factor variable (as otherwise it is likely numeric / integer).? Try `data1$state <- factor(data1$state)`. You can use the `levels` and `labels` arguments for more control.

Comment: also, by defining `state` as a factor variable, when it is passed to `lm` as a predictor it will automatically be converted into a matrix of dummy variables for you. So `lm(wages ~ factor(state), data=data1)`